# Use same postgres db for both Rail and Django project?

Tags: django, postgresql

Recently we are working with Rails Now want to attach module working with Django. Can We use same data Base for both project. Secondly postgresql db is used here.If any framework or gem present that can handle this.

Comment: Try to elaborate on your question. Detail the issue or give examples to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The cool thing about a general-purpose relational database (or actually one of the many cool things) is that you can use it with all kinds of programming environments – all you need to do is use the proper driver. So that should be no problem technically.

If the two programs work on the same data, let them share the database. If they operate on different data, create a new database.